# Why don't some query results have graph representation in Neo4j?

Tags: neo4j

In the Neo4j Browser, I performed one query as follows:

```
match (subject:User {name:{name}}) 
match (subject)-[:works_for]->(company:Company)<-[:works_for]-(person:User), 
(subject)-[:interested_in]->(interest)<-[:interested_in]-(person) 
return person.name as name, count(interest) as score, 
collect(interest.name) as interests order by score DESC
```

The result only has the "table" and "text" views, without the "graph". Normally, a query can generate a subgraph. Right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at your return, you're not returning any actual nodes or relationships. You're returning property values (strings), counts (longs), and collections of strings. If you returned `person` instead you would probably be able to see a graphical result, as the return would include data (id, labels, properties) that could be used to display graph elements.

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot.!